# Não consigo inserir nos campos DateTime no banco de dados sql

Tags: c#, sql

Não consigo inserir nos campos ***dataCriacao*** e **dataRefMovimento** no banco de dados sql

```
     private Contexto contexto;
    public void Inserir(RegCabecalho regCabecalho)
    {       
        var strQuery = "";
        strQuery += " INSERT INTO regCabecalho (tipoReg, dataCriacao,horaCriacao,dataRefMovimento,IDArq,codParceiro
      ,numeroSeq,versaoLayout) ";
      strQuery += string.Format(" VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}') " ,
      regCabecalho.tipoReg, regCabecalho.dataCriacao,
      regCabecalho.horaCriacao, regCabecalho.dataRefMovimento, regCabecalho.IDArq,
      regCabecalho.codParceiro,
      regCabecalho.numeroSeq, regCabecalho.versaoLayout
            );
        using (contexto = new Contexto())
        {
            contexto.ExecutaComando(strQuery);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Não consigo" é muito vago. O que acontece? Dá algum erro? Sem essas informações fica difícil alguém te ajudar.

Comment: Qual a mensagem de erro?

Comment: Qual banco de dados? você esta usando Entity FrameWork? onde você esta passando seu campo DateTime? para que serve RegCabecalho ?

Comment: sugestão, sempre insira a data no formato'aaaammdd' exemplo '20171201'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. Use alguma biblioteca de acesso a dados

[Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/data/jj200620), [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net), [alguma coisa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#.NET), mas não escreva SQL na mão. Ficar concatenando dados na mão no meio de SQL te deixa aberto [problemas de segurança](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL) e torna sua aplicação difícil de manter depois.

#### 2. Datas não tem representação universal nos bancos de dados

Você tem de entregar datas no padrão que o banco de dados espera, geralmente uma string formatada de um jeito específico. Você está concatenando os dados na mão, o que gera a data num formato string, mas que pode não ser o formato qual o banco está esperando.

Provavelmente seu computador está formatando datas no esquema dia/mês/ano, mas o banco está esperando no formato americano (mês/dia/ano) ou ainda no formato ISO 8601.

Crie a classe abaixo em algum lugar ...

```
public static class DateExtensions
{
    public static string ToIso8601Date( this DateTime date )
    {
        return date.ToString( "yyyy-MM-dd" );
    }
}
```

... e acrescente `ToIso8601Date()` ao final de `regCabecalho.dataCriacao` e `regCabecalho.dataRefMovimento`. Veja se funciona e depois comente aí.

Comment: Valeu ! obtive exito

Comment: De nada, e que bom que resolveu. Mas sério, pense em mudar de SQL manual para uma API de acesso a banco de dados. Esse problema que teve com data provavelmente vai ter com números com decimais (virgula vs ponto) e strings com aspas, apóstrofos... Coisas que não ocorrem com APIs de banco em que você não escreve o SQL.